# How do I pool a bullet in libgdx ashley ECS approach?

Tags: java, libgdx, entity-system, entity-component

I'm having problem creating bullet pool in ashley ECS approach, because i'm using PooledEngine, everything is pooled. So I've done is I just use `engine.createEntity()`, `engine.addEntity()` and `engine.removeEntity()` to spawn a bullet. The problem is, the bullet is not behaving properly. In this [memory-management](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Memory-management) bullet pool example, is working properly but not in ECS aproach. Can someone give me a brief explanation how do I pool a bullet in ashley ECS approach?

Comment: Are you perhaps holding a reference to the pooled object? This will cause many problems.